# Custom subsubsubsection command conflicts with tabular environment

Tags: tables, subsection

I use this command for 4 and 5 tiered subsections:

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% add subsubsubsection
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
% add subsubsubsubsection
\newcommand{\subsubsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem is that the pdf has the order wrong. The table comes after some of the subsubsubsection instances in the pdf in spite of preceding them in the code.

I assume that the command lacks the necessary parts to control position and make it act like a normal subsection.

Please help me complete the missing parts to make this command work better.

Edit:
an example for the table I'm using:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

2nd edit:
How can I add a positional argument for my command to be implemented like:

```
\subsubsubsection{some title}[h]
```

Edit 3: requested minimal example

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,                       % Papierformat
    oneside,                        % einseitig
    fontsize=13pt,                % Schriftgröße
    headsepline=.5pt,             % untere Kopfzeilenlinie
    numbers=noenddot,             % 1.1.1. --> 1.1.1
    parskip=half,                 % halber Absatz
    captions=tableheading,        % Tabellenüberschriften
    DIV=12,                       % Satzspiegel (KOMA-Script)
%   toc=bibliography,             % Quellenverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
    %tocdepth=3,                  % Begrenzung der Ebenen im Inhaltsverzecihnis
    %headings=normal,                           % Größe der überschriften verkleinern
    final                                                   % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrartcl}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%add subsubsubsection
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
%add subsubsubsubsection
\newcommand{\subsubsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{1st tier}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\subsection{2nd tier}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
 a & a & a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\subsubsection{3rd tier}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\subsubsubsection{4th tier}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\subsubsubsubsection{5th tier}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
a & a & a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\paragraph` **IS** already defined as the 4th level of document depth, not `\subsubsubsection`.

Comment: See [sectioning - How many levels of nested subsections can the article class support? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163676) and  [sectioning - How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209) and  [sectioning - Adding the fourth level of section - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517086) (... duplicate of the previous one?)

Comment: the package titlesec conflicts with the \section command, so it's not a good solution.

Comment: My question regards adding to my command information about correct positioning. I don't see how that could be a duplicate.

Comment: I tried using paragraph and it as well showed up in the wrong place so defining position in the command looks to me like a better solution.

Comment: If you are using the `table` environment, that is by definition a float, and will not necessarily appear in the same order you have input it.  To determine whether that is the case, more information is needed.  (What you have provided regarding sub...sections in that case may be entirely irrelevant.)

Comment: `\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}` breaks most of latex's section handling controlling page breaking after the section head. Just use `\paragraph `but declare it to be a display heading rather than run-in which you can do by directly modifying the definition or using titelsec

Comment: heading commands do not prevent floats such as tables moving. A `tabular` would not move, the only function of the `table` environment is to allow the table to move, that is unrelated to your definitions

Comment: please provide an actual test document you have provided two fragments but you presumably have not used both as they are contradictory, have you set `secnumdepth`  and `tocdepth` to 4 or 5?

Comment: When I remove tabular it won't compile.